# how to CREATE DIRECTORY in android sqlite database?

Tags: android, sqlite

i have to create a DIRECTORY in a database in which a few file will store.when user need any kind of file, the file fetches from that directory .

Comment: You're missing to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cerate a *directory* in an sqlite database.

Either you create a directory on the *filesystem* using [`File.mkdir`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29).

Or you create a *table* in a sqlite database. Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make directories in sqlite db.

Use android provided api for data storage read this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

Please first read about databases & then try to use it!!

**Database**:

[A database is an organized collection of data, today typically in digital form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database).

**Directory**:

[A directory or folder is nothing more than a location on a disk used for storing information about files](http://filext.com/faq/directory_folder_definition.php).